# Replacing cell content and eliminating duplicates in a DataGridView or DataTable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview

I've got my application in which an operator scans a barcode, the application then searching an SQL database and pulling the applicable records and placing them into a DataGridView. In one instance of the application, I need to "condense" what is displayed.

As an example, I have scanned a single barcode and been presented with the below 3 lines. What I need to do is bring this down to a single line after changing the 'Ref. Service' column to read 'Organic Acids' for all 3 line items. Note that all other columns are identical, this will always be the case.

[image]

The output should look like this, ignoring the red text as I've just used this to highlight the change.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to populate the datatable / datagridview.

```
Public Function GetResults() As DataTable

        Dim dtResults As New DataTable
        Dim connString As String = "Data Source=NP-SQ03\SQL;Initial Catalog=asl;User Id=;Password="

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("
                SELECT requests.request_id AS 'Request ID', patients.first_name AS GivenName, patients.surname AS Surname,
                concat(patients.day_birth, '/', patients.month_birth, '/', patients.year_birth) AS DOB, patients.sex AS 'Sex',
                services.service_abbrev AS 'Ref.Service', specimens.specimen AS 'Specimen', referral_details.referral_dt AS 'Referral Date'
                
                FROM
                { oj (((((((asl.dbo.requests requests INNER JOIN asl.dbo.requests_services requests_services ON
                requests.request_id = requests_services.request_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.referral_details referral_details ON
                    requests.request_id = referral_details.referring_request_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.patients patients ON
                    requests.patient_id = patients.patient_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.specimens specimens ON
                    requests_services.specimen_id = specimens.specimen_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.referral_details_services referral_details_services ON
                    requests_services.request_id = referral_details_services.request_id AND
                requests_services.service_id = referral_details_services.service_id)
                
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.labs labs ON referral_details.to_lab_id = labs.lab_id)
                INNER JOIN asl.dbo.services services ON referral_details_services.service_id = services.service_id)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN asl.dbo.addresses addresses ON labs.lab_address_id = addresses.address_id}

                WHERE
                    referral_details.referral_dt >= @StartDate AND
                    referral_details.referral_dt <= @EndDate AND
                    labs.lab_id = '55' AND
                    requests.request_id = @LabID
                
                ORDER BY
                    labs.lab_name ASC,
                    requests.request_id ASC,
                    services.service_abbrev ASC

                ", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTo.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LabID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtBarcode.Text
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dtResults.Load(reader)



Process:
                    If dtResults.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("This Lab ID cannot be added to the manifest because it is not in the referrals table. Please resolve and try again.", "No Referral", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Else
                        Return dtResults
                        'For Each dr As DataRow In dtResults.Rows
                        'dgScanned.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
                        'Next dr
                    End If
                Catch Ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to SQL Server. Please check your network connection and if required, report the issue to IT." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Ex.Message, "No Connection!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End Using

        End Using


    End Function
```

```
Private Sub txtBarcode_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtBarcode.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If txtBarcode.Text.Length < 7 Or txtBarcode.Text.Length > 7 Then
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("specierror.wav")
                MessageBox.Show("Scanned Lab ID is invalid. Please try again.", "Invalid Lab ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Else
                If GetResults() Is Nothing Then
                Else
                    For Each dr As DataRow In GetResults().Rows
                        dgScanned.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
                    Next dr
                    txtBarcode.Text = ""
                    txtBarcode.Focus()
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

I've seen plenty of examples elsewhere but can't seem to piece together something that will work for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: If all other columns are identical apart from Ref.Service where the user will enter a value that sounds like you want to apply to all visible records, why even show the 3 possible barcode matches?  Is there some significance to the original Ref.Service value that dictates some difference?

Comment: That looks like a Grouping on the value of a Column. You should clarify whether the result of this filter is meant to update the database in some way, or you're going to use that single row for something unrelated -- Anyway, you could update the DataSource of the DGV with something like `[DataTable] = [DataTable].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(function(dr) dr("Ref. Service")).Select(function(gp) gp.First()).CopyToDataTable()`. You can do that even in the `CellValueChanged` event of the DGV, assuming `[DataTable]` is the DataSource of your DGV

Comment: You can also use an `IEqualityComparer` object, as shown here: [How can I extract all Unique / Distinct Rows from a Datatable and save these rows in a new Datatable with same Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449655/7444103)